# Loading JSON data from server into knockout.js observable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to load initial data (from a local JSON string) using knockouts.js in order to displayed it in the UI right after loading the page.
I have tried a LOT of options but all failed or produce errors.

My latest try is http://jsfiddle.net/z22m1798/17/ (base on the 'Cart' example) which produce the error:

`TypeError: cartLine.filterValue is not a function`.

The relevant code is:

```
//Load initial data from server
var JSONdataFromServer =  $("#JSONdataFromServer").val();
console.log(JSONdataFromServer);
var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);
self.lines.push(new CartLine(dataFromServer));
```

Someone maybe know what am I doing wrong here?
It's look like a difficult issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the way to solve it (don't sure it is the most accurate way) is by receiving from the server the **entire** JSON so the first cells will contain the filters I wish to display. In addition, the server will send a parameter "filtersToDisplay" that indicate how many filters need to display.

By default, filtersToDisplay=1 to display only the first line.

http://jsfiddle.net/z22m1798/25/

```
 for (i = 0; i < $("#filtersToDisplay").val(); i++) { 
   self.lines.push(new CartLine(self.lines))// Put one line in by default
}
```

Thanks